# Hotmail, IMAP and Thunderbird

Tags: thunderbird, imap

Is there a way to sync to my hotmail account via IMAP on Thunderbird? Because i am having trouble connecting via IMAP. But if i switch to POP3 everything works fine. Am i doing something wrong in the configuration?

**UPDATE**: After a year finally there is IMAP support! Here are the settings:

Incoming IMAP

- Server: imap-mail.outlook.com
- Server port: 993
- Encryption: SSL

Outgoing SMTP

- Server: smtp-mail.outlook.com
- Server port: 587
- Encryption: STARTTLS

The settings above work also for hotmail and not only outlook!

Answer (score 1):

IMAP isn't supported by Microsoft on outlook.com.

There has been some [hints](http://gizmodo.com/5932972/?comment=51677253) that they might support it the future. But who knows when and if it will actually happen.

If you really really want to keep your email address you could get a google email account. Let your google mail account pop the hotmail emails over pop. then you can just run imap against your google account to recieve all your emails to your client over IMAP.